# Testing a handler that connects to db in go

Tags: go

I have a handler which connects to a db and retrieves the records. I wrote a test case for that and it goes this way:

## main_test.go

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "fmt"
  "testing"
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httptest"
)

var a App 

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    a = App{}
    a.InitializeDB(fmt.Sprintf("postgres://****:****@localhost/db?sslmode=disable"))
    code := m.Run()
    os.Exit(code)
}


func TestRulesetGet(t *testing.T) {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/1/sig/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    // We create a ResponseRecorder (which satisfies http.ResponseWriter) to record the response.
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(a.Get)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    // Check the response body is what we expect.

    if len(rr.Body.String()) != 0 {
      fmt.Println("Status OK : ", http.StatusOK)
        fmt.Println("handler returned body: got ",
            rr.Body.String())
    }
}
```

I feel like this is a very basic test case where I'm just checking the response length (This is because I expect a slice). I'm not really sure whether this is the right way to write a test case. Please point out some loop holes so that I could write a solid test cases for my remaining handlers. And also, I'm not using the actual `Error`, and `Fatal` methods for checking the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works then it's not wrong, but it doesn't validate much, only that the response body is non-empty - not even that it's successful. I'm not sure why it prints out `http.StatusOK`, which is a constant, and doesn't tell you what the status code in the response was.

Personally when I do this level of test I check, at the very least, that the response code is as expected, the response body unmarshals correctly (if it's JSON or XML), the response data is basically sane, etc. For more complex payloads I might use a [golden file](http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2016/integration-testing-with-golden-masters/) test. For critical code I might use a [fuzz (aka monte carlo) test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing). For performance-critical code I'll likely add benchmarks and load tests. There are practically infinite ways to test code. You'll have to figure out what your needs are and how to meet them.

Comment: I've never heard of the above testing techniques. I'll definitely look into them!